# Algorithm to compare images

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

I'm thinking of writing an app that can compare images: i.e. check if one image exists inside another.

Let's imagine a picture with people, trees and another stuff. Let's imagine another picture of a tree. Is it possible to check if that second picture has some similarity with the trees in the first picture?

I've tried to read bytes and compare them but it didn't work.

What's the best approach to do something like this? What is the algorithm that i should use? And what is the best ( faster ) language to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are generally many ways to do things like this, with the best way, or maybe the only possible way, depending on the details.  Is the tree or other object in the second image exactly the same size as in the first? Perhaps smaller but otherwise identical? Or are you looking for approximately similar shapes, not minding fine detail?  Would things be lit the same in both images? If not, does it matter? Would it count if an object in the second image is found in the first, but the background or other objects in the second don't exist in the first?

Comment: The objects could be in different sizes. Inside the first picture you could have a tree from type "a". When i took this picture, i send it to my app to check what's the name from that tree. Imagine that i have a lot of jpeg files of trees and i would like to determine what file have the closest tree from the picture that i sent. What is the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Look at openCV, follow the link :

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pHash algorithm from here:http://www.phash.org.

Answer (score 0):

[SURF](http://opencvuser.blogspot.se/2012/03/surf-algorithm-for-matching.html) and [SIFT](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) are two good algorithms, widely available in libraries for languages of your choice.

It is also instructive to imple.ent them yourself in your preferred language to familiarise yourself with this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need algorithm similar to fast algorithm of searching substring in a string, but developed to search in 2D space.

For example, here is good solution:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.581&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Its complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>) in worst case, where n is dimension of big matrix.

Comment: This is for string pattern, right? I didn't figure out how to search inside images files.

Comment: @DavidL. "string" and "alphabet" are just abstractions. In your image, every pixel has its value from given range, so it can be presented as "character" and whole image can be presented as "2D matrix of characters".

Comment: got it but can i work with it if the image can be smaller, darker??

Comment: such kind of task is closer to artificial intelligence and data mining